# how i can take string input from user and change only the letter and odd digit to upper case in assembly language

Tags: assembly

how i can take string input from user and change the letter only to upper case and must change the only odd digit in string in assembly language ? example the user input yasmine12 the output must be YaSmInE12

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense. What happened to `12 wasfi` in the output? As for how you'd do this, it's not really any different from any other programming language: check if the character is `>= 'a' AND <= 'z'` and the index is odd, and if so subtract `'a' - 'A'` (which for ASCII equals `0x20`) from that character.

Comment: What CPU? (x86, Power, MIPS, ARM, 8080,...)

Comment: the CPU 8086 and i repair the example above

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to convert the string. But I can't tell you how to read and output a string, because this depends on what OS you're using.

```
jmp start
text db "yasmine12",0  ;a null-terminated string
start: 
lea si, text
lea di, text
loop_block:
lodsb
or al, al 
jz end      ;jump to the end of the program, if the null-byte at the end of the string is reached
mov ah, al
cmp ah, "a"
jb omit
cmp ah, "z" ;test whether the letter is a lowercase
ja omit
shr ah, 1  ;test whether the letter is odd
jnc omit
sub al, 32 ;convert lowercase to uppercase
omit:      ;label to which the program springs if the char shouldn't be converted
stosb      ;overwrite the old char with the new char
jmp loop_block  
end:
;put the code here to output the string and end the program
```

Comment: If you look at the example then you'll see that it is not the oddness of the ASCII code that must be tested. It's the characters at EVEN positions that are capitalized!